# Ponteiros Inteligentes

Tags: c++, ponteiro, smart-pointer

Estava estudando ponteiros inteligentes e com base neste blog: https://murilo.wordpress.com/2008/12/15/smart-pointers-os-ponteiros-espertos-do-c/

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>  class SmartPointer 
{
        T *ptr; public:
        SmartPointer(T *p):ptr(p) {}

        ~SmartPointer() {delete ptr;}

        T& operator*() {return *ptr;}

        T* operator->() {return ptr;} 
};


int main() 
{
  SmartPointer str(new std::string("Testando Smart Pointers"));
  std::cout << *str << " size: " << str->size() << std::endl; 
}
```

mas ao compilar o mesmo ele retorna este erro:

```
ex2.cxx: In function ‘int main()’: ex2.cxx:20:18: error: missing
template arguments before ‘str’
     SmartPointer str(new std::string("Testando Smart Pointers"));
                  ^~~ ex2.cxx:21:19: error: ‘str’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << *str << " size: " << str->size() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro está no próprio código original, portanto já sabe que a fonte não é boa.

Na verdade quando vai procurar informações sobre tecnologia e outras coisas na internet deve olhar a data. Se for muito antigo tem grande chance de estar defasado se não for um fundamento.

Esse é um caso, ali ensina coisas que não se deve fazer mais. Na verdade sempre houve controvérsia naquele uso.

Para aprender use fontes que foram avaliadas, [como a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). E veja a [documentação de tudo de gerenciamento de memória do C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Assim funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto str = std::make_unique<std::string>("Testando Smart Pointers");
    std::cout << *str.get() << " size: " << str->size() << std::endl; 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4PEmF5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lszcuyli-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/UniqueString.cpp).

Esse código não é necessário, o exemplo já é ruim. Está criando um ponteiro para algo que na verdade usará um ponteiro. `string` do C++ meio que já é um ponteiro inteligente (internamente). Então isso não faz sentido. Está criando uma indireção para algo que já é uma indireção. Isso até pode ser útil, mas são casos bem diferentes do aplicado.

Comment: entao o exemplo em si é ruim sim mas o que eu pensei foi tentar entender o funcionamento disso pra fazer nas minhas classes e structs em c++ pra nao ter que ficar manipulando ponteiro ou se preocupando em deletar ponteiros achei interessante a proposta mas ainda nao tenho ideia de como fazer da forma mais correta possivel para futuras utilizaçoes nas classes ou programa desenvolvidos na linguagem...

Comment: Mais ou menos. A preocupação sempre deve existir. Isto ajuda, mas não é algo a prova de bala. Tem várias coisas que podem dar errado mesmo com estes ponteiros. Claro que sabendo usar, analisando se não pode ser algum efeito indesejado vai legal, mas está longe de ser simples como é *marketado*