# std::list::clear libera objetos adicionados à lista com new?

Tags: c++, lista, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, stl

Usando C++, o método `clear()` de `std::list` exige que os elementos tipo `std::list<int>` alocados com new e inseridos à lista geral sejam liberados manualmente com delete para não gerar vazamento de memória?

Exemplo de código:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    list<int>* l;
}Test;

void ftest(list<Test>* l) {
    Test t;
    t.l = new list<int>;
    l->push_back(t);
}

int main()
{
    list<Test> *l = new list<Test>;
    ftest(l);
    ftest(l);
    l->clear(); //liberar manualmente todas as list<int> criadas com new em ftest()?
    delete l;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que está fazendo precisa liberar item por item alocado com `new` para não vazar memória.

Só lembrando que para um exemplo assim não importa muito porque o código termina logo em seguida e tudo será resolvido, mas em um caso real teria que fazer o correto e chama o `delete` para todos os itens, antes de ar o `clear()`, que tornaria esses itens inacessíveis em condições normais, mas ainda em memória.

Para isto que existem o [ponteiros inteligentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260076/101). Usando-os o gerenciamento passa ser automático e a liberação dos itens chamaria o `delete` sozinho para você, é a forma recomendada de fazer, `new` e `delete` raramente devem ser usados diretamente, vale até para a alocação principal, embora no caso apresentado nem precisaria ter sido colocado ho *heap*, o que tornaria mais fácil.